# '$fileReqInvisibleField' is already declared in the upper scope

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarlint

For the bellow function, I get the following warning on 3 different places:

**'$fileReqInvisibleField' is already declared in the upper scope.**

**Explanation**

`$fileReqInvisibleField` is declared on line 49:

```
const $fileReqInvisibleField = $(`#${fileReqId}`)
```

Later on line 101 it is passed as an argument to the outer-function **addValidator** as follows:

```
function addValidator ($fileReqInvisibleField) {

    $.validator.register({
      selector: `#${$fileReqInvisibleField.attr('id')}`,
      validate: validate,
      show: show,
      clear: clear
    })

   ...

}
```

But it's also passed to 3 inner-functions inside the parent function **addValidator**:

```
function addValidator ($fileReqInvisibleField) {
    ...

    function validate ($fileReqInvisibleField) { ... }


    function show ($fileReqInvisibleField, message) { ... }


    function clear ($fileReqInvisibleField) { ... }

    ...
}
```

This caused a **SonarLint** warning on all those 3 inner-functions as follows:

**$fileReqInvisibleField hides or potentially hides a variable declared in an outer scope at line 101.**

Does it mean that I just need to remove $fileReqInvisibleField as an argument for those 3 inner-functions?

If I do this, will those 3 inner-functions take the value from their outer-function?

Would it be the right solution to get rid of the SonarLint warnings without breaking the functionality?

Comment: Yes it looks like your functions `validate`, `show` and `clear` are within the scope of the `addValidator` function. This means they already have access to the `$fileReqInvisibleField` and it doesn't need to be added as an argument

Comment: Thanks. This file is part of a huge project and I'm not entirely sure where it is used. After removing those arguments, what would be the best way to make sure that the functionality is not broken?